# Return only the first element of an std::pair when calling a function that returns std::pair

Tags: c++, std-pair

I'm using a function that returns an `std::pair`:

```
std::pair<bool, int> myFunction() {
    //Do something...

    if (success) {
        return {true, someValue};
    }
    else {
        return {false, someOtherValue};
    }
}
```

On success, the pair's first value will be `true`, otherwise `false`.

Some functions that call `myFunction()` use the returned pair's second value, others don't. For those, I'm calling `myFunction()` like this:

```
bool myOtherFunction() {
    //Do something...

    bool success;
    std::tie(success, std::ignore) = myFunction(); //I don't care about the pair's second value

    return success;
}
```

Is there a way to avoid declaring `bool success` and returning `myFunction()`'s return value's first element directly?

Comment: Did you try `return myFunction().first;`  ?

Comment: Maybe you should look at the [documentation for `std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair#Non-member_functions).

Comment: @ArnavBorborah: Thanks. I did know `std::pair` members `first` and `second`, but somehow didn't think about using them on function call.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

a `std::pair` is just a struct with 2 values; so just return the "first" item in the struct.

```
return myFunction().first;
```

Comment: ... of course! Now it seems obvious to me. Thank you, that works very fine for my use case.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps

```
return std::get<0>(myFunction());
```

or

```
return std::get<bool>(myFunction());
```